# Quick question regarding second moment

Tags: probability, actuarial-science

The following question is what I was working on.

> a% of the population has a risk of incurring damage that has a Poisson distribution with mean 1.  Similarly, b% has a distribution with mean 2 and the rest (c%) has a distribution of with mean 3.  A random person is chosen from this population and has a mean damage of 2.59 and a variance of 2.1.  Find the probability of no claims occurring.

I understand that the weighed mean can be figured out as $$a(1)+b(2)+c(3)=2.1$$

However, I am not quite understanding why my book tells me that the second moment is found by $$a(2)+b(6)+c(12)=2.59+2.1^2$$

I understand the right hand side because it's simply

$$Var[x]+(E[X])^2=E[X]$$

But I though that the second moment should be $$a(1^2)+b(2^2)+c(3^2)$$

Can someone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: You probably have a typo in $Var[x]+(E[X])^2=E[X]$ and may have intended $Var[x]+(E[X])^2=E[X^2]$

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are measuring the second moment about zero using your $E[X^2] = Var[X]+(E[X])^2$ then you want

$$E[X^2]= aE[X_1^2]+bE[X_2^2]+cE[X_3^2] = a(1+1^2)+b(2+2^2)+c(3+3^2)$$ on the left hand side.

Comment: Ah, I see now. thank you!